# Can I have "warning" messages for fields in Formik?

Tags: formik

I've just learned Formik and would like to use it in a real life project. I would like to assign "warnings" to field inputs as well as "errors". As far as I understood, Formik just supports "errors".

- Is there a way to decorate field **values with "warnings" in Formik**, something like a "warnings" object maybe?

Any help highly appreciated!